# MODIS getHdf : Error in .local(product, ...) : Problems with online connections try a little later

Tags: gdal, r, modis, modis-reprojection-tool

I have a big problem today, i have this error while i'm executing my script :

```
Error in .local(product, ...) :    Problems with online connections try a little later
```

My script :

```
b1 <- getHdf(product = "MOD09GA", begin = "2018.03.01", end = "2018.03.02", tileH = 22, tileV = 02)
```

It worked well on sunday but today i get this error. I changed nothing in my environment.

Does someone has the same error for today ?

Or is it my environment fault ?

I tried others products but I have got an other error (for MOD11C3) :

```
Error in if (FtpDayDirs[1] == FALSE) { : valeur manquante là où TRUE / FALSE est requis
```

It is in french, but it tells me that there is a missing value where TRUE or FALSE is required. Maybe this product is deprecated for these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution : the servers goes offline 1 or 2 days a week to push new MODIS images. So you will have this error some days each week.